# image invisible after adding div

Tags: jquery, css, imageflow

i am using [imageFlow](http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Introduction) for making an image slider. i have added on click Flip functionality to images. my problem is i want to add a div around images to show description but when i add the div around images it becomes invisible. i don't know how to update js file .

Please suggest,

```
/* ImageFlow constructor */
```

function ImageFlow ()
{

```
/* Setting option defaults */
this.defaults =
{
    animationSpeed:     100,             /* Animation speed in ms */
    aspectRatio:        1.964,          /* Aspect ratio of the ImageFlow container (width divided by height) */
    buttons:            false,          /* Toggle navigation buttons */
    captions:           false,           /* Toggle captions */
    circular:           true,          /* Toggle circular rotation */
    imageCursor:        'default',      /* Cursor type for all images - default is 'default' */
    ImageFlowID:        'imageflow',    /* Default id of the ImageFlow container */
    imageFocusM:        1.0,            /* Multiplicator for the focussed image size in percent */
    imageFocusMax:      3,              /* Max number of images on each side of the focussed one */
    imagePath:          '',             /* Path to the images relative to the reflect_.php script */
    imageScaling:       true,           /* Toggle image scaling */ 
    imagesHeight:       0.67,           /* Height of the images div container in percent */
    imagesM:            1.0,            /* Multiplicator for all images in percent */
    onClick:            function() { /*document.location = this.url;*/ flipIt(this) },   /* Onclick behaviour */
    opacity:            true,          /* Toggle image opacity */
    opacityArray:       [10,8,6,4],   /* Image opacity (range: 0 to 10) first value is for the focussed image */
    percentLandscape:   118,            /* Scale landscape format */
    percentOther:       100,            /* Scale portrait and square format */
    preloadImages:      false,           /* Toggles loading bar (false: requires img attributes height and width) */
    reflections:        false,           /* Toggle reflections */
    reflectionGET:      '',             /* Pass variables via the GET method to the reflect_.php script */
    reflectionP:        0.5,            /* Height of the reflection in percent of the source image */
    reflectionPNG:      false,          /* Toggle reflect2.php or reflect3.php */
    reflectPath:        '',             /* Path to the reflect_.php script */
    scrollbarP:         0.6,            /* Width of the scrollbar in percent */
    slider:             false,           /* Toggle slider */
    sliderCursor:       'e-resize',     /* Slider cursor type - default is 'default' */
    sliderWidth:        17,             /* Width of the slider in px */
    slideshow:          false,          /* Toggle slideshow */
    slideshowSpeed:     1500,           /* Time between slides in ms */
    slideshowAutoplay:  false,          /* Toggle automatic slideshow play on startup */
    startID:            1,              /* Image ID to begin with */
    glideToStartID:     true,           /* Toggle glide animation to start ID */
    startAnimation:     false,          /* Animate images moving in from the right on startup */
    xStep:              180             /* Step width on the x-axis in px */
};


/* Closure for this */
var my = this;
//console.log(my)

/* Initiate ImageFlow */
this.init = function (options)
{
    /* Evaluate options */
    for(var name in my.defaults) 
    {
        this[name] = (options !== undefined && options[name] !== undefined) ? options[name] : my.defaults[name];
    }

    /* Try to get ImageFlow div element */
    var ImageFlowDiv = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID);
    if(ImageFlowDiv)
    {
        /* Set it global within the ImageFlow scope */
        ImageFlowDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
        this.ImageFlowDiv = ImageFlowDiv;

        /* Try to create XHTML structure */
        if(this.createStructure())
        {
            this.imagesDiv = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_images');
            this.captionDiv = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_caption');
            this.navigationDiv = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_navigation');
            this.scrollbarDiv = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_scrollbar');
            this.sliderDiv = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_slider');
            this.buttonNextDiv = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_next');
            this.buttonPreviousDiv = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_previous');
            this.buttonSlideshow = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_slideshow');

            this.indexArray = [];
            this.current = 0;
            this.imageID = 0;
            this.target = 0;
            this.memTarget = 0;
            this.firstRefresh = true;
            this.firstCheck = true;
            this.busy = false;

            /* Set height of the ImageFlow container and center the loading bar */
            var width = this.ImageFlowDiv.offsetWidth;
            var height = Math.round(width / my.aspectRatio);
            document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_loading_txt').style.paddingTop = ((height * 0.5) -22) + 'px';
            ImageFlowDiv.style.height = height + 'px';

            /* Init loading progress */
            this.loadingProgress();
        }
    }
};


/* Create HTML Structure */
this.createStructure = function()
{
    /* Create images div container */
    var imagesDiv = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','images');

    /* Shift all images into the images div */
    var node, version, src, imageNode;
    var max = my.ImageFlowDiv.childNodes.length;
    for(var index = 0; index < max; index++)
    {
        node = my.ImageFlowDiv.childNodes[index];
        if (node && node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName == 'IMG')
        {
            /* Add 'reflect.php?img=' */
            if(my.reflections === true)
            {
                version = (my.reflectionPNG) ? '3' : '2';
                src = my.imagePath+node.getAttribute('src',2);
                src = my.reflectPath+'reflect'+version+'.php?img='+src+my.reflectionGET;
                node.setAttribute('src',src);
            }

            /* Clone image nodes and append them to the images div */
            imageNode = node.cloneNode(true);
            imagesDiv.appendChild(imageNode);
        }
    }

    /* Clone some more images to make a circular animation possible */
    if(my.circular)
    {
        /* Create temporary elements to hold the cloned images */
        var first = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','images');
        var last = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','images');

        /* Make sure, that there are enough images to use circular mode */
        max = imagesDiv.childNodes.length;
        if(max < my.imageFocusMax)
        {
            my.imageFocusMax = max;
        }

        /* Do not clone anything if there is only one image */
        if(max > 1)
        {
            /* Clone the first and last images */
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                /* Number of clones on each side equals the imageFocusMax */
                node = imagesDiv.childNodes[i];
                if(i < my.imageFocusMax)
                {
                    imageNode = node.cloneNode(true);
                    first.appendChild(imageNode);
                }
                if(max-i < my.imageFocusMax+1)
                {
                    imageNode = node.cloneNode(true);
                    last.appendChild(imageNode);
                }
            }

            /* Sort the image nodes in the following order: last | originals | first */
            for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                node = imagesDiv.childNodes[i];
                imageNode = node.cloneNode(true);
                last.appendChild(imageNode);
            }



            for(i = 0; i < my.imageFocusMax; i++)
            {
                node = first.childNodes[i];
                imageNode = node.cloneNode(true);
                last.appendChild(imageNode);
            }

            /* Overwrite the imagesDiv with the new order */
            imagesDiv = last;

        }


    }

    /* Create slideshow button div and append it to the images div */
    if(my.slideshow)
    {
        var slideshowButton = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','slideshow');
        imagesDiv.appendChild(slideshowButton);
    }

    /* Create loading text container */
    var loadingP = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('p','loading_txt');
    var loadingText = document.createTextNode(' ');
    loadingP.appendChild(loadingText);

    /* Create loading div container */
    var loadingDiv = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','loading');

    /* Create loading bar div container inside the loading div */
    var loadingBarDiv = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','loading_bar');
    loadingDiv.appendChild(loadingBarDiv);

    /* Create captions div container */
    var captionDiv = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','caption');

    /* Create slider and button div container inside the scrollbar div */
    var scrollbarDiv = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','scrollbar');
    var sliderDiv = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','slider');
    scrollbarDiv.appendChild(sliderDiv);
    if(my.buttons)
    {
        var buttonPreviousDiv = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','previous', 'button');
        var buttonNextDiv = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','next', 'button');
        scrollbarDiv.appendChild(buttonPreviousDiv);
        scrollbarDiv.appendChild(buttonNextDiv);
    }

    /* Create navigation div container beneath images div */
    var navigationDiv = my.Helper.createDocumentElement('div','navigation');
    navigationDiv.appendChild(captionDiv);
    navigationDiv.appendChild(scrollbarDiv);

    /* Update document structure and return true on success */
    var success = false;
    if (my.ImageFlowDiv.appendChild(imagesDiv) &&
        my.ImageFlowDiv.appendChild(loadingP) &&
        my.ImageFlowDiv.appendChild(loadingDiv) &&
        my.ImageFlowDiv.appendChild(navigationDiv))
    {
        /* Remove image nodes outside the images div */
        max = my.ImageFlowDiv.childNodes.length;
        for(index = 0; index < max; index++)
        {
            node = my.ImageFlowDiv.childNodes[index];
            if (node && node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName == 'IMG')
            {
                my.ImageFlowDiv.removeChild(node);
            }
        }
        success = true;
    }
    return success;
};


/* Manage loading progress and call the refresh function */
this.loadingProgress = function()
{
    var p = my.loadingStatus();
    if((p < 100 || my.firstCheck) && my.preloadImages)
    {
        /* Insert a short delay if the browser loads rapidly from its cache */
        if(my.firstCheck && p == 100)
        {
            my.firstCheck = false;
            window.setTimeout(my.loadingProgress, 100);
        }
        else
        {
            window.setTimeout(my.loadingProgress, 40);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* Hide loading elements */
        document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_loading_txt').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_loading').style.display = 'none';

        /* Refresh ImageFlow on window resize - delay adding this event for the IE */
        window.setTimeout(my.Helper.addResizeEvent, 1000);

        /* Call refresh once on startup to display images */
        my.refresh();

        /* Only initialize navigation elements if there is more than one image */
        if(my.max > 1)
        {
            /* Initialize mouse, touch and key support */
            //my.MouseWheel.init();
            //my.MouseDrag.init();
            my.Touch.init();
            my.Key.init();

            /* Toggle slideshow */
            if(my.slideshow)
            {
                my.Slideshow.init();
            }

            /* Toggle scrollbar visibility */
            if(my.slider)
            {
                my.scrollbarDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }
    }
};


/* Return loaded images in percent, set loading bar width and loading text */
this.loadingStatus = function()
{
    var max = my.imagesDiv.childNodes.length;
    var i = 0, completed = 0;
    var image = null;
    for(var index = 0; index < max; index++)
    {
        image = my.imagesDiv.childNodes[index];
        if(image && image.nodeType == 1 && image.nodeName == 'IMG')
        {
            if(image.complete)
            {
                completed++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    var finished = Math.round((completed/i)*100);
    var loadingBar = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_loading_bar');
    loadingBar.style.width = finished+'%';

    /* Do not count the cloned images */
    if(my.circular)
    {
        i = i - (my.imageFocusMax*2);
        completed = (finished < 1) ? 0 : Math.round((i/100)*finished);
    }

    var loadingP = document.getElementById(my.ImageFlowID+'_loading_txt');
    var loadingTxt = document.createTextNode('loading images '+completed+'/'+i);
    loadingP.replaceChild(loadingTxt,loadingP.firstChild);
    return finished;
};


/* Cache EVERYTHING that only changes on refresh or resize of the window */
this.refresh = function()
{
    /* Cache global variables */
    this.imagesDivWidth = my.imagesDiv.offsetWidth+my.imagesDiv.offsetLeft;
    this.maxHeight = Math.round(my.imagesDivWidth / my.aspectRatio);
    this.maxFocus = my.imageFocusMax * my.xStep;
    this.size = my.imagesDivWidth * 0.5;
    this.sliderWidth = my.sliderWidth * 0.5;
    this.scrollbarWidth = (my.imagesDivWidth - ( Math.round(my.sliderWidth) * 2)) * my.scrollbarP;
    this.imagesDivHeight = Math.round(my.maxHeight * my.imagesHeight);

    /* Change imageflow div properties */
    my.ImageFlowDiv.style.height = my.maxHeight + 'px';

    /* Change images div properties */
    my.imagesDiv.style.height =  my.imagesDivHeight + 'px'; 

    /* Change images div properties */
    my.navigationDiv.style.height =  (my.maxHeight - my.imagesDivHeight) + 'px'; 

    /* Change captions div properties */
    my.captionDiv.style.width = my.imagesDivWidth + 'px';
    my.captionDiv.style.paddingTop = Math.round(my.imagesDivWidth * 0.02) + 'px';

    /* Change scrollbar div properties */
    my.scrollbarDiv.style.width = my.scrollbarWidth + 'px';
    my.scrollbarDiv.style.marginTop = Math.round(my.imagesDivWidth * 0.02) + 'px';
    my.scrollbarDiv.style.marginLeft = Math.round(my.sliderWidth + ((my.imagesDivWidth - my.scrollbarWidth)/2)) + 'px';

    /* Set slider attributes */
    my.sliderDiv.style.cursor = my.sliderCursor;
    my.sliderDiv.onmousedown = function () { my.MouseDrag.start(this); return false;};

    if(my.buttons)
    {
        my.buttonPreviousDiv.onclick = function () { my.MouseWheel.handle(1); };
        my.buttonNextDiv.onclick = function () { my.MouseWheel.handle(-1); };
    }

    /* Set the reflection multiplicator */
    var multi = (my.reflections === true) ? my.reflectionP + 1 : 1;

    /* Set image attributes */
    var max = my.imagesDiv.childNodes.length;
    var i = 0;
    var image = null;
    for (var index = 0; index < max; index++)
    {
        image = my.imagesDiv.childNodes[index];
        if(image !== null && image.nodeType == 1 && image.nodeName == 'IMG')
        {
            this.indexArray[i] = index;

            /* Set image attributes to store values */
            image.url = image.getAttribute('longdesc');
            image.xPosition = (-i * my.xStep);
            image.i = i;

            /* Add width and height as attributes only once */
            if(my.firstRefresh)
            {
                if(image.getAttribute('width') !== null && image.getAttribute('height') !== null)
                {
                    image.w = image.getAttribute('width');
                    image.h = image.getAttribute('height') * multi;
                }
                else{
                    image.w = image.width;
                    image.h = image.height;
                }
            }

            /* Check source image format. Get image height minus reflection height! */
            if((image.w) > (image.h / (my.reflectionP + 1)))
            {
                /* Landscape format */
                image.pc = my.percentLandscape;
                image.pcMem = my.percentLandscape;
            }
            else
            {
                /* Portrait and square format */
                image.pc = my.percentOther;
                image.pcMem = my.percentOther;
            }

            /* Change image positioning */
            if(my.imageScaling === false)
            {
                image.style.position = 'relative';
                image.style.display = 'inline';
            }

            /* Set image cursor type */
            image.style.cursor = my.imageCursor;
            i++;
        }
    }
    this.max = my.indexArray.length;

    /* Override dynamic sizes based on the first image */
    if(my.imageScaling === false)
    {
        image = my.imagesDiv.childNodes[my.indexArray[0]];

        /* Set left padding for the first image */
        this.totalImagesWidth = image.w * my.max;
        image.style.paddingLeft = (my.imagesDivWidth/2) + (image.w/2) + 'px';

        /* Override images and navigation div height */
        my.imagesDiv.style.height =  image.h + 'px';
        my.navigationDiv.style.height =  (my.maxHeight - image.h) + 'px'; 
    }

    /* Handle startID on the first refresh */
    if(my.firstRefresh)
    {
        /* Reset variable */
        my.firstRefresh = false;

        /* Set imageID to the startID */
        my.imageID = my.startID-1;
        if (my.imageID < 0 )
        {
            my.imageID = 0;
        }

        /* Map image id range in cicular mode (ignore the cloned images) */
        if(my.circular)
        {   
            my.imageID = my.imageID + my.imageFocusMax;
        }

        /* Make sure, that the id is smaller than the image count  */
        maxId = (my.circular) ?  (my.max-(my.imageFocusMax))-1 : my.max-1;
        if (my.imageID > maxId)
        {
            my.imageID = maxId;
        }

        /* Toggle glide animation to start ID */
        if(my.glideToStartID === false)
        {
            my.moveTo(-my.imageID * my.xStep);
        }

        /* Animate images moving in from the right */
        if(my.startAnimation)
        {
            my.moveTo(5000);
        }
    }

    /* Only animate if there is more than one image */
    if(my.max > 1)
    {
        my.glideTo(my.imageID);
    }

    /* Display images in current order */
    my.moveTo(my.current);
};


/* Main animation function */
this.moveTo = function(x)
{
    //alert(x)
    this.current = x;
    this.zIndex = my.max;


    /* Main loop */
    for (var index = 0; index < my.max; index++)
    {
        var image = my.imagesDiv.childNodes[my.indexArray[index]];
        var currentImage = index * -my.xStep;

        /* Enabled image scaling */
        if(my.imageScaling)
        {
            /* Don't display images that are not conf_focussed */

            if ((currentImage + my.maxFocus) < my.memTarget || (currentImage - my.maxFocus) > my.memTarget)
            {
                image.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                image.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else
            {
                var z = (Math.sqrt(10000 + x * x) + 100) * my.imagesM;
                //var z = (Math.sqrt(10000) + 500) * my.imagesM;
                var xs = x / z * my.size + my.size;

                /* Still hide images until they are processed, but set display style to block */
                image.style.display = 'block';

                /* Process new image height and width */
                var newImageH = (image.h / image.w * image.pc) / z * my.size;
                var newImageW = 0;
                switch (newImageH > my.maxHeight)
                {
                    case false:
                        newImageW = image.pc / z * my.size;
                        break;

                    default:
                        newImageH = my.maxHeight;
                        newImageW = image.w * newImageH / image.h;
                        break;
                }

                var newImageTop = (my.imagesDivHeight - newImageH) + ((newImageH / (my.reflectionP + 1)) * my.reflectionP);

                /* Set new image properties */
                image.style.left = xs - (image.pc / 2) / z * my.size + 'px';
                if(newImageW && newImageH)
                {
                    image.style.height = newImageH + 'px';
                    image.style.width = newImageW + 'px';
                    image.style.top = newImageTop + 'px';
                    /*
                     newImageTop="100.239";
                     newImageH="250";
                     newImageW="210";
                     image.style.height = newImageH + 'px';
                     image.style.width = newImageW + 'px';
                     image.style.top = newImageTop + 'px'; */
                }
                image.style.visibility = 'visible';

                //console.log("LEFT  == " +image.style.left);
                //console.log("TOP   ==" + newImageTop)


                /* Set image layer through zIndex */
                switch ( x < 0 )
                {
                    case true:
                        this.zIndex++;
                        break;

                    default:
                        this.zIndex = my.zIndex - 1;
                        break;
                }

                /* Change zIndex and onclick function of the focussed image */
                switch ( image.i == my.imageID )
                {
                    case false:
                        image.onclick = function() {  my.glideTo(this.i);};
                        break;

                    default:
                        this.zIndex = my.zIndex + 1;
                        if(image.url !== '')
                        {
                            image.onclick = my.onClick;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                image.style.zIndex = my.zIndex;
            }
        }

        /* Disabled image scaling */
        else
        {
            if ((currentImage + my.maxFocus) < my.memTarget || (currentImage - my.maxFocus) > my.memTarget)
            {
                image.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            else
            {
                image.style.visibility = 'visible';

                /* Change onclick function of the focussed image */
                switch ( image.i == my.imageID )
                {
                    case false:
                        image.onclick = function() { my.glideTo(this.i);};
                        break;

                    default:
                        if(image.url !== '')
                        {
                            image.onclick = my.onClick;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }   
            my.imagesDiv.style.marginLeft = (x - my.totalImagesWidth) + 'px';
        }

        x += my.xStep;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code you're generating it's difficult to say exactly what's going on, but I'd guess that adding divs around your images is screwing up the format that ImageFlow is looking for when laying out the images.

Are your descriptions long? If not, you might be able to add them as alt tags to the image and then enable captions in your ImageFlow options. The alt tag description would then show up as a caption on the image.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the code for ImageFlow, I mean the code you're creating. Did you try enabling captions?

Comment: nope ... cause i have paragraph in description and that too i want to show on top of image

Comment: How are you doing the flip? Are you using a jquery plugin, if so, which one?